# Google calendar returns not a valid json file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, calendar

We are making a website with AngularJS. We need the google calendar events.
I try to load the data from a Google Calandar.

here you can find the json file: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/nmk97b3l07ncb9f9h5ap5ffo2c@group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json-in-script&callback=insertAgenda&orderby=starttime&max-results=15&singleevents=true&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true

But Angulair does not recognize it as a json file.

Is there a way to get this as json file?

Comment: It is JSON. It's just encased in a callback.

Comment: The JSON input is NOT valid according to RFC 4627 (JSON specification). Unexpected token // API callback...  
use json validator.

Comment: Why not using a library like Moment.js to convert the data to something standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insertAgenda` is the jsonp-callback-parameter.

Try this:

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/nmk97b3l07ncb9f9h5ap5ffo2c@group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json-in-script&callback=insertAgenda&orderby=starttime&max-results=15&singleevents=true&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true';

$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'insertAgenda', //The callback parameter in Google Calendar response
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
       console.dir(json);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aJ3zS/)